# Google app verification lost from google apps script project when sheet is copied

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth-2.0

I Developed a google app scripts application that uses a spreadsheet as its database,
 
I give the app to customers by giving them a URL to make a copy from the spreadsheet (the script is on that spreadsheet) and they authorize and use the copy.
 
Lately, my customers are getting an "Unverified App" screen before authorizing the script. so I filled out a form for google verification and **Google verified it**, but my **customers still get the unverified screen...**
I suspect that the problem is that each sheet gets a **new Project Id and client id when copied**, so the google verification does not apply to them.
Does anyone know a solution that I can have the copies verified as well? or is there another way to give the app to people without requiring them making a copy and still everybody should have his own script and spreadsheet?

Comment: What is the complete error message that your users got?

Comment: there is no error message, just that new "unverified app" screen

Comment: Please, can you show a screenshot of the "unverified app" screen?

Comment: here is a link to where Google explains the verification etc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

Comment: My understanding is that currently there's no way around this issue. Once your customers have copied the spreadsheet, they also become the owners of the bound script. So, strictly speaking, they run the copies of the script that are unverified, not your original script.

Comment: You could create a installable add-on or a web app to serve as a single entry point After you verify them, he app can then copy the file from your Drive to customer's account

Comment: Does this mean that we have reached the end of the container bound script era? the only way to use it is by sharing or face an 'unverified screen'?

Comment: Hi David, I have the exact same problem with a spreadsheet I sell that uses a script to identify the user. I verified that making a copy of the spreadsheet indeed changes the Project ID, causing the "unverified" screen to be displayed. Since no _real_ solution seems to exist as of yet, I am considering to either 1) remove my script entirely, or 2) make a short tutorial how users can click on "Advanced" and then "Proceed" to still use the spreadsheet despite the "unverified" warning.

@AntonDementiev Your suggestion would still allow users to freely share the spreadsheet with others

Comment: Hi kregus, The only solution is to use a web app. what I did is. 1) instead of the user making a copy of the sheet I use Google apps scripts driveApp.makeACopy() method to get the copy and for obtaining the copy for when the script is running, I save the copies id in storage and use open by id to read and write data to and from it. I can show you the code if you want

Comment: You should post that as an answer David. You'll get some more rep points, and a badge.

Comment: I am having the same issue. My question is what is the point of having verified my app if it can't be shared with others except through the proposed work around? I feel like something must be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no solution to retain the same project id when making a copy, you can publish your project as a web app and have the web app creating the sheet for you and use that sheet to read and write data.
Here is what I did

```
   function getCustomSpreadsheet(){
        //try to get the spreadsheet id of the already created spreadsheet
        var ssid = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('customSsid');
        //if sheet does not exist, create it
        if(!ssid) var ssid = createCustomSpreadsheet();
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
        return ss;
   }

   function createCustomSpreadsheet(){
        //make a copy of your template spreadsheet and save its id to a property
        fileId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//your ss id here
        var ss = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy();
        var ssid = ss.getId();
        PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('customSsid', ssid);
        return ssid;
  }
```

I found/replaced everywhere in my code `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` to `getCustomSpreadsheet()` and lived happely ever after...